# Distribution of final digits of consecutive primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

There's been [a lot in the press recently](http://www.nature.com/news/peculiar-pattern-found-in-random-prime-numbers-1.19550) about the [unexpected distribution of final digits in pairs of consecutive primes](http://arxiv.org/abs/1603.03720), and many people have written programs to confirm the observation that pairs with the same last digit are relatively uncommon.

But this heatmap shows a curious (near-)symmetry about one of the diagonals, when comparing the probabilities: is this unexpected too or is there a simple explanation (or mistake) I'm missing?

[image]

i.e. the probability of a 7 followed by a 1, P(7,1) is close to the probability P(9,3); P(1,3) is close to P(7,9), etc. How is it that the probabilities are similar when considering pairs of last-digit pairs differing by the same number (mod 10) (e.g. 1-7 = 3-9, 3-1 = 9-7).

Comment: What's the range of the data?

Comment: First 10,000,000 primes greater than 5

Comment: A very interesting observation. Would you mind providing some links for 'a lot in the press'?

Comment: @YuriyS http://www.nature.com/news/peculiar-pattern-found-in-random-prime-numbers-1.19550 and arXiv link in this article

Answer (score 2):

Call the lower prime $p_1$ and the higher prime $p_2$.

The counts of prime-pairs mod 10, for $5<p_1<p_2$ among the first 10,000,000 primes, are as follows:

$\begin{array}{|r|rrrr|}\hline
 & 1 & 3 & 7 & 9\\ \hline
1 & 446808 & 756071 & 769924 & 526953\\
3 & 593196 & 422302 & 714795 & 769915\\
7 & 639384 & 681759 & 422289 & 756852\\
9 & 820369 & 640076 & 593275 & 446032\\ \hline
\end{array}$

Call an integer "admissible" if it's coprime to 10. One factor making certain sequences less frequent than others is that the former entail at least a certain number of admissible numbers $p_1<n<p_2$ being composite. For example (1, 1) entails at least 3 such. This, however, does not explain how come (7, 3) is more frequent than (7, 1) and (9, 3).

To get a clearer picture of what's going on, I refined the profiling of primes by classifying each prime by its residue class modulo 30.
Every prime $p>5$ is in one of the following residue classes modulo 30:
1, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29.
Now, call an integer "admissible" if it's in any of those residue classes. This now means that multiples of 3 are no longer admissible.

Each of your 16 categories mod 10 becomes 4 subcategories mod 30. For example, (1, 7) mod 10 becomes (1, 7), (1, 17), (11, 7) and (11, 17) mod 30. For each such category $(r_1, r_2)$, calculate $c$, the lower bound on the number of admissible $p_1<n<p_2$ that would have to be composite, for $p_1=r_1$ and $p_2=r_2\mod 10$. Some examples:

```
(1, 7) mod 10: 0, 3, 6, 1.
(9, 1) mod 10: 2, 4, 0, 2.
(7, 3) mod 10: 1, 4, 6, 1.
(7, 1) mod 10: 6, 0, 3, 5.
(9, 3) mod 10: 5, 0, 3, 6.
```

What do these values of $c$ correspond to, in terms of numbers of prime-pairs? At least among the first 10,000,000 primes, and with $c<7$, I find that increasing $c$ by 1 reduces the number of prime-pairs by a factor of roughly 1.2 to 1.25, and increasing $c$ from 6 to 7 reduces it by a factor of roughly 1.42. In particular, $c=0$ produces the greatest number of prime-pairs. $(r_1, r_2)=(9, 1)\mod 10$ has a $c=0$ and no $c>4$; no wonder there are so many prime-pairs in that category.

The stats for prime-pairs in subcategories mod 30:

$\begin{array}{|r|rrrrrrrr|}\hline
 & 1 & 7 & 11 & 13 & 17 & 19 & 23 & 29\\ \hline
1 & 56340 & 290569 & 236714 & 195717 & 154909 & 123368 & 107932 & 84032\\
7 & 73841 & 57775 & 294863 & 238438 & 193766 & 158877 & 124856 & 107667\\
11 & 95005 & 83726 & 58749 & 294325 & 240720 & 195866 & 158097 & 123687\\
13 & 119037 & 97111 & 88452 & 58571 & 297438 & 240651 & 193751 & 155139\\
17 & 177521 & 112547 & 93159 & 80134 & 58201 & 294330 & 238331 & 195978\\
19 & 195635 & 145749 & 136030 & 93158 & 88644 & 58459 & 295256 & 236761\\
23 & 239773 & 223009 & 145934 & 112090 & 97237 & 83474 & 57890 & 290651\\
29 & 292429 & 239596 & 196275 & 177717 & 119286 & 94667 & 73945 & 56145\\ \hline
\end{array}$